# A strange error with a struct as a parameter

Tags: c

I received following very odd error:

```
   24 | void InitList(LinkList &L)
      |                        ^
main.c:31:24: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘&’ token
   31 | void InitList(LinkList &L);
      |                        ^
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:36:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘InitList’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   36 |     InitList(&L);
      |     ^~~~~~~~
```

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct LNode
{
    int data;
    struct LNode* next;
}*Link, *Position;
typedef struct LinkList
{
    Link head,tail;
    int len ;
}LinkList;
struct LNode* NewNode()
{
    struct LNode* p;
    p = (struct LNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct LNode));
    p->next=NULL;
    if (p == NULL)
        exit(-1);
    return p;
}

void InitList(LinkList &L)
{
    Link p=NewNode();
    L.head=L.tail=p;
    L.len=0;
}

void InitList(LinkList &L);
int main()
{
    int M,i;
    LinkList L;
    InitList(&L);
}
```

Comment: References are a feature of C++, not C.

Comment: Write `LinkList *L` instead of `LinkList &L`.

Comment: Do note that when you change `L` from C++ reference to C pointer, you also need to change `L.` to `L->` inside `InitList()`.

Comment: As a side note: `struct LNode* p;<newline>  p = (struct LNode*)malloc(sizeof(struct LNode));` is better written as `struct LNode* p = malloc(sizeof *p);`. Declaration and initialization in one step, no unnecessary cast and don't write the type twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

References are a feature of C++, not C. You are trying to accept a reference to a `LinkList`.